# 'I cittadini belgi' Vs. 'i cittadini belga'

Tags: plural

Secondo voi, si dice 'i cittadini belgi' o 'i cittadini belga'?

Secondo me, 'i cittadini belga' è corretto certamente nella misura in cui s'accetti il sottinteso 'di nazionalità' lì, cioè 'i cittadini *di nazionalità* belga', ma, forse, potrebbe essere corretto in assoluto.

'I cittadini belgi' potrebbe essere corretto, tuttavia appare cacofonico.

Cosa ne pensate?

Comment: Tu dici “i cittadini italiana” sottintendendo “di nazionalità”?

Comment: Elberich devo dire che le tue domande mi lasciano sempre estremamente confuso. Esattamente dove hai mai sentito *i cittadini belga*? O quando mai si usa omettere il *di nazionalità*?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Tuttavia si può trovare su alcune pagine web, come per esempio qui: http://www.lastampa.it/2014/09/20/esteri/la-sede-della-commissione-ue-nel-mirino-dellisis-fermate-due-persone-a-bruxelles-89LEwavz6D4UoteUpcuLsN/pagina.html

Comment: @Charo Devo, a malincuore, ammettere che si può, ma la differenza di frequenza mi fa pensare che si tratti di refusi piuttosto che di scelte volontarie. Tra l'altro l'articolo che citi usa entrambe le forme. Per esempio vedi https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cittadini+belga%2Ccittadini+belgi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccittadini%20belgi%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Charo: Sono certo che sia un errore, o una confusione di chi ha scritto. C'è addirittura una barzelletta, proprio sul plurale di “belga” (belgi? belghi? belga?), con il protagonista che alla fine scrive “un belga, anzi no: due”. Succede qualcosa di simile, e pure peggio, con “dalmati” detto degli abitanti della Dalmazia (dove “dalmata” al plurale è ammesso, seppure, per il nome della razza canina).

Comment: @dag bellissime 'ste barzellette, ahahahahahahah

Comment: Una ricerca su Google di `"cittadini belga"` riporta 98 occorrenze. Sufficiente per trarne una conclusione: chi l'ha scritto non sapeva che il plurale di “belga” è “belgi”.

Comment: cacofonico ma corretto.  Se troppo cacofonico usa una qualche perifrasi: i cittadini del Belgio.

Answer (score 6):

Il Treccani, così come anche il Garzanti, dice: cittadini "belgi", cittadine "belghe".
"Belga" rimane la forma corretta per il sostantivo maschile e femminile singolare.

Perciò la tua variante "cittadini belga" è scorretta, mentre è corretta la "cacofonica" (a tuo dire!) cittadini "belgi".